# Why is setValue in registerDefaults give me a warning with BOOL YES?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following lines in my code:

```
[registerDefaults setValue:NO forKey:UserDefaultsGameSortAscendingKey];
[registerDefaults setValue:YES forKey:UserDefaultsReminderSortAscendingKey];
```

Why is it that I am getting a warning on the second line and not the first?

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Both `UserDefaultsGameSortAscendingKey` and `UserDefaultsReminderSortAscendingKey` are defined as constants:

```
extern NSString *const UserDefaultsGameSortAscendingKey;
extern NSString *const UserDefaultsReminderSortAscendingKey;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the BOOLs as NSNumbers to store them into defaults:

```
[registerDefaults setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:UserDefaultsGame...];
[registerDefaults setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES] forKey:UserDefaultsGame...];
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but it's not a cast. It would be more accurate to say you need to wrap the BOOL.

Comment: Clarification reflected in edit. My definition of "casting" pretty much matches wikipedia's, however: In computer science, type conversion, typecasting, and coercion refers to different ways of, implicitly or explicitly, changing an entity of one data type into another.

Comment: At least in C-derived languages, a "cast" refers to changing the type of something without actually changing the in-memory representation. However in this case, you're wrapping the BOOL value with an `NSNumber` object, and the resulting value has a different in-memory representation than the original BOOL.

Comment: This (wrapping) process is also called boxing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing

Comment: @KevinBallard, absolutely a useful distinction to C, and I've amended the answer accordingly. The term *cast* is perhaps less fitting (hence the amendment), but still useful to describe this general computing concept, particularly to someone who may not be versed in C but to whom "cast" may already be understood and thus comprehended more quickly than the terms "wrap" or "box", which are more specifically accurate but less obvious to someone not already familiar.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setBool:forKey:`.  This will eliminate the warning (which @isaac's answer explains the cause of), save you time writing code, and be less error prone since any casting/conversion is done for you:

```
[registerDefaults setBool:NO forKey:UserDefaultsGameSortAscendingKey];
[registerDefaults setBool:YES forKey:UserDefaultsReminderSortAscendingKey];
```

[From the NSUserDefaults Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/NSUserDefaults_Class.pdf#page21):

> ```
> setBool:forKey:
> ```
>
> Sets the value of the specified default key to the specified Boolean
>   value.
>
> ```
> - (void)setBool:(BOOL)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
> ```
>
> `value`
>   The Boolean value to store in the defaults database.
>
> `defaultName`
>   The key with which to associate with the value.

Comment: I assume that the `registerDefaults` in the original question indicates the dictionary used to set the default values with the method: `- (void)registerDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dictionary`. Unfortunately `- (void)setBool:(BOOL)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName` can't be used in this case.

Comment: @A could be a regular dict or the NSUserDefaults, guess we won't know without the OP clarifying.  Downvoting based on an assumption that can't be confirmed is not right though.  Downvotes should be used on answers that are clearly wrong, poor quality, spam, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as others pointed out, you should use setBool:forKey: or wrap the BOOL in a NSNumber. Now to answer your actual question:

setValue:forKey: is defined as:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

value is of type id which is a pointer to any kind of object. NO evaluates to 0, or nil, which is a valid version for a variable of type id (or any pointer). YES evaluates to 1, which is not a valid value for a variable of type id. Hence the warning.